# Children within an element wont align horizontally

Tags: html, css

I have a wrapper box that can't be overflowed.

An inner box that contains children.

Those children need to be aligned horizontally and can't be allowed to break to a second line.

If there are too many children than I wish a horizontal overflow of the inner box but not the outer box.

I can't get the children to not line break so the scroll bar ends up being useless.

The children will align horizontally with float: left which line breaks and flex which crushes the children to fit.

I found three pages with a similar issue here on stack overflow and tried them but none worked.
Not sure if that makes this forbidden as a duplicate or not.

I suspect it is the rotation of the elements which is throwing things off weirdly.

CodePen: https://codepen.io/Tygari/pen/mdJQZVw

**CSS**

```
class{
    display: block;
    height: 210px;
    width: 70vw;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
    border: 1px solid black;
    overflow: hidden;
}
info{
    display: block;
    height: 10%;
    width: 70vw;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
    border: 1px solid black;
}
archetype{
    display: inline-block;
    height: 90%;
    width: 100%;
    overflow: scroll;
    overflow-y: hidden;
}
.foo > archetype,
.bar > archetype,
.baz > archetype,
.foobar > archetype,
.foobaz > archetype,
.barfoo > archetype,
.barbaz > archetype{
    display: none;
}
#foo div div div::before{
    content: 'Foo';
}
#bar div div div::before{
    content: 'Bar';
}
#baz div div div::before{
    content: 'Baz';
}
#foobar div div div::before{
    content: 'Foobar';
}
#foobaz div div div::before{
    content: 'Foobaz';
}
#barfoo div div div::before{
    content: 'Barfoo';
}
#barbaz div div div::before{
    content: 'Barbaz';
}
.diamond{
    height: 125px;
    width: 125px;
    margin-left: 60px;
    text-align: center;
    border: 1px solid black;
    transform: translate(-30px,30px) rotate(45deg);
}
.diamond div{
    position: relative;
    border: 1px solid black;
    left: 50%;
    top: 50%;
    transform: translate(-50%,-50%);
    height: 100px;
    width: 100px;
}
.diamond div div{
    border: 1px solid black;
    left: 50%;
    top: 50%;
    transform: translate(-50%,-50%);
    height: 75px;
    width: 75px;
}
.diamond div div div{
    left: 50%;
    top: 50%;
    transform: translate(-50%,-50%) rotate(-45deg);
    height: auto;
    width: auto;
    border:none;
}
```

**HTML**

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/gh/tygari/echo-js/echo.js" sync></script>
<class>
   <info></info>
   <archetype class="archetype" echo="foo bar baz foobar foobaz barfoo barbaz" code="<div class='diamond' 
      ><div><div><div></div></div></div></div>"> 
   </archetype>
</class>
```

**DOM**

```
<class>
   <info></info>
   <archetype class="archetype" echo="foo bar baz foobar foobaz barfoo barbaz" code="<div class='diamond' 
      onclick='this.parentNode.parentNode.className += this.id'><div><div><div></div></div></div></div>">
      <div id="foo" class='diamond'><div><div><div></div></div></div></div>
      <div id="bar" class='diamond'><div><div><div></div></div></div></div>
      <div id="baz" class='diamond'><div><div><div></div></div></div></div>
      <div id="foobar" class='diamond'><div><div><div></div></div></div></div>
      <div id="foobaz" class='diamond'><div><div><div></div></div></div></div>
      <div id="barfoo" class='diamond'><div><div><div></div></div></div></div>
      <div id="barbaz" class='diamond'><div><div><div></div></div></div></div>
   </archetype>
</class>
```

Solved by adding "display: flex;" to archetype element and "flex-shrink: 0;" to .diamond class.

Comment: The code doesn't seem to be workable. Can you provide a sandbox ?

Comment: @Knick Added a CodePen to help.

Comment: If this question is solved, consider answering your own question and mark it as answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved by adding "display: flex;" to archetype element and "flex-shrink: 0;" to .diamond class.